# Some of my datatable column shows as number datatype in excel how to prevent it defined as number without comma delimiter

Tags: excel, datatable, export

I have 4 columns in datatables and wanted to export into xlsx file 2 of the column, one column is name and phone, but after export, one of the column (phone) will show millions as 1,000,000 for example. I wish that phone number column to be treated as text but failed many times

This is my code and loading the data from json text using php

```
$(document).ready(function() 
                    {
                        $('#example').DataTable( {

                            "ajax": "json.php",
                             "pageLength": 100,
                            "deferRender": true,
                            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                            lengthMenu: [
                                [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
                                [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', '100 rows', '200 rows' , '500 rows', '1000 rows']
                            ],
                            buttons: ['pageLength','copy', 
                               {extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                filename: 'export',
                                title: null,
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [ 1, 2 ],
                                    format: {
                                    body: function (data, row, column, node ) 
                                    {
                                        return column === 2 ? "\0" + data : data;
                                        //return column === 2 ?  = & "" + data : data;                                      
                                    }

                                  },

                               }
                          }
                        ],
                    } );
                    } );
```

Comment: TEH XXX XXX 60,164,551,207
the second column shows as number not behaving as text

Comment: Still appear as 60,164,221,207

Comment: How many columns does your datatable have?

Comment: 4, but want to export column 2 and 3 only

Comment: Is it in excel you are having this issue?

Comment: yes only in excel

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your code then. Excel just keeps removing the 0 since it sees it as a number not a text. You have to apply some formatting; eg. could you add dashes? See [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/88044/#Comment_88044)